# Can't find C# class template file in Visual Studio folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, templates

I am trying to create an Visual Studio 2010 Add-In that when run adds a class to the opened solution's first project using **EnvDTE**.

I've managed to create the add-in, get the reference to the opened solution and get the reference to the first project.

Then I want to **create the class**, and I've found the following code:

```
String templatePath = sol.ProjectItemsTemplatePath(PrjKind.prjKindCSharpProject);
templatePath += @"\CSharpAddClassWiz.vsz";
```

The path points to a template file that does not exist. Everywhere I try to get this file, it’s stated that “you could find it in Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\CSharpProjectItems”

Here’s the entire content of this folder in my installation of Visual Studio 2010:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFsMw.png

In fact I’ve searched for the file, and even for *.vsz in my entire hard drive, and **nothing** was found.

**I have two questions:**

**1)**  Did I install Visual Studio incorrectly, so that this file is not available in the Visual Studio folders?
**2)**  How can I get this file, even if it is a copy of it?

I do realize that having a copy of it and shipping it in with my Add-In would mean that in the future, people could generate classes with an old template, rather than the updated ones found in their Visual Studio folders, but I just want to proceed with my tests, 
generate this class, and move on until I have the first question solved.

---

There are two things that intrigue me on this matter:

- Doesn't Visual Studio use these files while I'm creating classes through it's wizards?
- I have Visual Studio 2008 installed too, and it also lacks these files.

Comment: Can't anyone upload it (maybe in dropbox) and link it to me so that I can use it and go on until I find a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to run a repair on Visual Studio, it is likely that there was an error during the install.

Comment: I'm running the repair right now, I'll report back here right after it's conclusion

Comment: Nope.. Completely uninstalled and re-installed it, and no new files in any folder.